# MySQL extract max numbers from string regexp

Tags: mysql, regex, string, numbers

I would like to extract maximun number contained in string with REGEXP.

Here my string from Freq row:

```
AG=0.00, CA=0.26, TA=0.00, TG=1.04
```

Desired output: `1.04`

I tried to do that:

```
select `Freq` from tablename where `Freq` REGEXP '/([\d.]+)/';
```

But it returns an empty result.

Comment: This smells a bad DB-design. Think about normalization

Comment: data are inserted like that in DB due to different allele frequency on DNA. Plus it doesn't help anything.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`